# What are the chances of winning Accordion Solitaire?

Tags: solitaire, statistics

I would like to know what are the chances of winning in both versions:

1. laying out the cards one by one
2. laying out the entire deck at the game start

Comment: What are you considering to be a win condition?

Comment: I mean getting all the cards in a single pile.

Comment: Are you looking for if you have prefect play or just how often player win?

Answer (score 5):

**Accordion**

According to one of the biggest player on the solitaire market (SolSuite), the game of Accordion (one card at a time version) has a chance of winning in about 1 of 200 games, i.e. 0,5%

[image]

But I would actually say that there is no difference in the winning percentage (if played right) between the two versions you are talking about, since (*in the one card at a time version*) you could always lay out the entire deck first one card at a time before starting to play...

[image]

Comment: There is probably a difference in the win percentage. If you lay out the entire deck first, you have perfect information about which moves are most beneficial. By flipping cards one at a time and making decisions as you go, you may make a choice that in hindsight was worse (i.e.: your piles could have been more appropriately condensed).

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest publication that compute the solvability of 45 solitaire games, Accordion is almost always solvable.

> Freecell, Spider, and Accordion...are all very close to 100% solvable.

Source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.12314.pdf

[image]

Comment: I suspect that there some difference in the rules between this Accordion and the one in the answer that state only 0.5% winnability.

Answer (score -2):

At least one of each three games can be won in the version where you lay out the entire deck. Just follow these strategy tips:

You should select four cards of the same rank, clustered near each other and near the end of the layout. The strategy is to try to get all four selected cards to the end of the layout and never cover them with anything else until the very end of the game.

Comment: Is the link you provided pointing to a site you control or take part of?

Comment: I have changed my answer according to your remarks.

Comment: Are you estimating a 1/3 solution rate based on personal experience?  Or some database?

Comment: My estimation is based on my personal experience while playing Accordion in BVS Solitaire Collection.